# laravel relationship one to many

Tags: laravel, relationships

before anything ,Highly appreciated in advance for help . i have two model
user:

```
public function posts(){
return $this->hasMany('App\Post');}
```

post:

```
public function user(){
return $this->belongsTo('App\user');}
```

my post have column "user_id" so every post have owner "user_id".

here is my question: i want to delete user but nothing happen to related post. right now i can do this ,but my problem is post_id column have id belongs to deleted user. i want to change that to "null" or "0".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with model events. Something like this on your User model.

```
public static function boot() {
  parent::boot();

  static::deleting(function($user) {
    $user->posts()->update(['user_id' => null]);
  });
}
```

Also make sure the user_id field is nullable on the migration.

Comment: Cool, just mark the correct answer so anyone who searches this problem will know which is correct.

Comment: sorry can give you vote , dont have enough reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure that your `post_id` field is set to nullable in your migration AND in your database.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with SQL power - add a migration to your table "posts"
...

```
$table->foreign('user_id')
    ->references('id')->on('users')
    ->onDelete('set null');
```

It will create a foreign key which sets null to related field on deleting user row

Comment: first thanks, i try it but for some reason not work,i use migration and first drop foreign key and then define new one ,just one you said it.but when i delete user , nothing happen to user_id.do i need something else?

Comment: Not sure anything more is required.
But AFAIR, you can't delete a record while it has some referrenced rows from other tables if FK is created and no correct action  set ON DELETE.
E.g. if you have an FK and ON DELETE NO ACTION, deleting parent row will fail with "foreign key constraint failed". It's true on postgres and Mysql InnoDB, not sure on others.
So please double check if an FK was created.
E.g. on mysql you can cast "SHOW CREATE TABLE t_posts"

Comment: thank you so much , i checked and suddenly found out my engine is "MyISAM" and fk not working on it. so after change it to "InnoDB" , everything work like charm.sorry can give you vote , dont have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the function boot() from User model:

```
protected static function boot() {
  parent::boot();

  static::deleting(function($user) {
    $user->posts()->delete();
  });
}
```